# Wordpress Multisite - Mapping Multiple Domain Names - As Primary

Tags: wordpress, multisite

Alright, the primary domain is: gdengines.com. I also own .net & .org. I want it so if a user types in .net or .org it will display the primary domains contents. However, the LINKS will be for that URL (the easiest way to explain this is by using the following plugin as an example:

Multiple Domain ([plugin page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domain/)) - Multiple Domain allows you having more than one domain in a single WordPress installation. When there is more than one domain set in your host, all links and resources will point to the default domain. This is
the default WordPress behavior. With Multiple Domain installed and properly configured, it’ll update all link on the
fly. This way, the user navigation will be end-to-end under the same domain.

However, the plugin doesn't work with multisite installations.

I have [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) installed, but it's not helping for this issue.

Anyone know a fix other than setting up .net & .org to redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use on the other domains .htaccess file with.

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.your-url.com
```

If you have to on each domain then redirect the vistor automatic to your main domain.